How to Fine-Tune Pre-Trained Stable Diffusion Models Using Custom Images
I am utilizing Stable Diffusion XL Base 1.0 for image generation, but it does not accept my custom input image. I would like to generate a new image based on my input image and the specified prompt.
I need a solution to generate anthropomorphic pet portraits from user-uploaded pet photos. Specifically, I want the AI to use the pet's face from the uploaded image and create the rest of the body based on a given prompt, such as a king, doctor, or lawyer. The generated portraits should retain the pet's unique features, making it clear they are the same pets.
The problem I'm encountering is that when I input a custom pet image into the pre-trained Stable Diffusion model with an anthropomorphic prompt, the model generates an image based on its dataset instead of using my custom image. I want the AI to generate new images using the provided pet photos, incorporating the given prompt, rather than creating random images from its own dataset.
How can I fine-tune a pre-trained Stable Diffusion model, or any relevant model, with our custom images so that it uses these images to generate new portraits according to the given input and prompt?

You may have to gather enough image samples of what you expect to it to be. You can use existing models or techniques to preprocess your data. Once you get more image data, normalise the data
